# Used 'disable' command on NPC - how do I get him back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I disabled an NPC named Tolfdir because he kept attacking me because my auto click went on and attacked him.  He kept attacking me and I can't load a previous save.  I disabled him, left the building and went back in and tried re-enabling him and I haven't seen him since.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

To target an NPC in the console without clicking on him with the console open, you can use [`prid <RefID>`](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29#Other) command:

> Sets the NPC as reference, allowing other commands to be used, good for targeting NPCs that you can't reach/select on screen or fixing quest glitches about NPCs not appearing.

Once a target is selected, Name and RefID will be displayed in the center of the screen. The `RefID` for Unique NPCs can be usually be found on the wiki, such as [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tolfdir), in the basic information box. For Tolfdir, it is `0001C1A1`. Do not confuse it with the BaseID.

So, in total, to get Tolfdir back, open the console and type:

```
prid 0001C1A1
enable
```